# How to connect to MySQL server from C# / C++ application?

Tags: c++, mysql, client-side

This is purely theoretical question, I'm not doing anything, but I plan to.

Is it possible to connect to your web server database with full access from a C++ / C# application without showing the server access data?

For example, an application like oDesk Team. It gets all data the user has on the website too. Are they using the same database? Of course, we can't know their technical details, but is it possible?

Pls note that I've never done real programming, only web programming and some Java for practice. I want to learn C++ and C# and I'm interested if I can combine my previous knowledge with the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can make a webservice or directly accessing the database. In C + + you have the gSOAP library to consume webservice.